# Compiling verilog packages with same name

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Verilog 2K has support for compiling modules with different implementation using the "config" facility. In my multi chip uvm env I need to use 2 different packages(chip_top_pkg.sv) which have exactly the same name but different uvm components.

Is there a way to compile them separately and use them at elaboration. Or do I necessarily have to prefix all package names with say unique chip name?

-sanjeev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, SystemVerilog `packages` are used early in the compilation process and must be declared before they can be referenced. `Module` elaboration happens much later in the process, which allows later bindings for the `config` construct.

So your `package` names must be unique across the system.